# What does it mean when two voids are in a parameter name in C?

Tags: c, parameters, void

I have a method I need to fill in and one of the parameters is: "void (*destructor)(void*)".  Can anyone tell me what this is?

Comment: Quite handy: http://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 4):

It is a **[Function pointer](http://www.function-pointer.org/)**.

It stores address of an function which takes a `void *`(pointer to `void`) as an input parameter and returns no parameter.

Comment: takes one parameter of type void*

Comment: @wildplasser: Ah that was hard to spot lol i missed it, thanks

Comment: well, it saved you two minutes of typing, and yielded (probably) 45 karma-points.

Comment: @wildplasser: You mean the *imaginary rep*, Fortunately or Unfortunately, I have collected quite enough of those to to answer a for collecting those anymore.

Answer (score 1):

That's a function pointer. The function given should have the signature:

```
void funcname(void*)
```

The first void is the return type, the second is a pointer to void (in other words, a pointer to who knows what, which the underlying function will presumably cast to some useful type later).

Answer (score 1):

The `void (*destructor)(void*)` is a function pointer. This means, that you can use it to point to any function, which has void as return value (returns nothing) and expects an generic pointer (`void*`), which can point to anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's pointer to a function that takes a `void*` as its only argument, and returns nothing.